# Reorder of newform and editform its different

Tags: 2010, development

I have a list which editform and newform fields order is different, the question is why? somebody told me the edit form might be unghosted, if so, how can I confirm this and revert it so that it uses the same order of the new form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could see different field ordering because some of the Fields have ShowOnDisplayForm=TRUE but ShowOnEditForm=FALSE.

Finally, you can check to see if the page is unghosted/customised using PowerShell.

Say the Url of the Page is `http://sharepoint/lists/mylist/editform.aspx`

Then in PowerShell do the following:-

`$web = Get-SPWeb "http://sharepoint";`

`$editFormPage = $web.GetFile("/lists/mylist/editform.aspx");`

`$editFormPage.CustomisedPageStatus;`

If its ghosted/uncustomized then it will say:-
CustomizedPageStatus    : Uncustomized

If its unghosted/customized then it will say:-
CustomizedPageStatus    : Customized

Regards

Simon